# Default image didn't change Django

Tags: django, templates, django-models

I try to make avatar upload in Django project. I made changes in templates and in models, but the default image does not change to a new one. What could be the problem?

> model.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="img", null=True, blank=True)
```

> template.html

```
            {% if person.avatar.url %}
                <th scope="row"><img height="50" width="50" src="{{ person.avatar.url }}"
                                     alt="no image" title="avatar">
                    {% else %}
                <th scope="row"><img height="50" width="50" src="{% static "img/default_avatar.jpg" %}"
                                     alt="no image" title="avatar">
            {% endif %}
```

Comment: Likely you do not pass `person` to the context...

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe you mixed `'` and `"` in `src="{% static 'img/default_avatar.jpg' %}"`

Answer (score 1):

Giving a default image is easier. You don't need to write an if statement every time using an avatar pic anymore

*models.py:*

```
class Person(models.Model):
    avatar = models.ImageField(default="img/default.png", upload_to="img", null=True, blank=True)
```

*template.html:*

```
<th scope="row><img height="50" width="50" src="{{ person.avatar.url }}" alt="no image" title="avatar">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{% if person.avatar %}
 <th scope="row"><img height="50" width="50" src="{{ person.avatar.url }}"
                                     alt="no image" title="avatar">
 {% else %}
  <th scope="row"><img height="50" width="50" src="{% static "img/default_avatar.jpg" %}"
                                     alt="no image" title="avatar">
  {% endif %}
```